# how to make the Sharepoint workflow history readable

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

How do we make the SharePoint Online Workflow history list readable to an auditor?

I would like to have the List ID be the Name of the list and also the Item ID be the name of the Item.

I have been digging around but no luck so far.